# How can I compile a HTA application into a single EXE?

Tags: compilation, exe, hta

I would like to compile an HTA application and all of its required files and directories, how could I do that. I found an HTA editor that will compile the `.hta` to an EXE, but not its required files and dir's. I would also like to change the icon of the file as it shows in explorer. I would also like the exe to act a single directory even though there is dir's inside of it. If that make any sense? That part doesn't matter as long as the rest works.

Comment: The fast I can get this there better, thanks guys :)

Comment: Just google some "HTA to EXE compilers". I can recall there's a "compiler" available (not free), which does pretty much what you need. FYI, no matter which compiler you use, they all extract the files from an EXE, and save the files to a temporary folder during execution...

Comment: [This approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25571255/2165759) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use exescript and add required folders and files to resource menu of Exescript.