# MSGbox in VBS that updates with value of variable

Tags: vbscript

Just wondering how i could have a MSgbox that displays the value of a variable as it constantly changes. Basically a number has one added to it everytime it loops. I want to display that in a MSGbox that doesnt have to open a million windows

Comment: Both `MsgBox` and `InputBox` are modal. If you want to display a modeless window, you'll need to launch an ActiveX server or OLE window (like Internet Explorer) or create an HTA. Alternatively, you could output the variable's value to STDOUT using CSCRIPT.

Comment: Check [this WSH VBS GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47111556/2165759) solution. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22546774/2165759) may be helpful also.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A workaround would be to use `PopUp`

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
For i = 1 To 3
    objShell.Popup i, 1, "AutoClose MsgBox Simulation", vbInformation+vbOKOnly
Next
```

This will "autoclose" the MsgBox lookalike after 1 second

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this with the default VBScript dialog elements, like `MsgBox`, `WScript.Echo` or `Popup`. You need to build a [custom dialog](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_ui_buttons.php) using the Internet Explorer COM object:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "about:blank"

While ie.ReadyState <> 4 : WScript.Sleep 100 : Wend

ie.ToolBar   = False
ie.StatusBar = False
ie.Width     = 300
ie.Height    = 200

ie.document.body.innerHTML = "<p id='msg'>0</p>"

Set style = ie.document.CreateStyleSheet
style.AddRule "p", "text-align: center;"

ie.Visible = True

i = 1
Do
  ie.document.getElementById("msg").innerText = i
  i = i + 1
  WScript.Sleep 2000
Loop Until i > 10
```

or use an [HTA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx) instead of plain VBScript:

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="oHTA"
  APPLICATIONNAME="Test"
  SCROLL="no"
>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
  p {text-align: center;}
</style>

<script language="VBScript">
  window.resizeTo 300, 200

  Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  Sub Window_onLoad
    For i = 1 To 10
      msg.innerText = i
      Sleep 2
    Next
  End Sub

  Sub Sleep(t)
    sh.Run "ping -n " & (t+1) & " 127.0.0.1", 0, True
  End Sub
</script>

<body>
<p id="msg">0</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

One more solution, uses HTA window, without temp files:

```
dim window, i

set window = createwindow()
window.document.write "<html><body bgcolor=buttonface>Current loop is: <span id='output'></span></body></html>"
window.document.title = "Processing..."
window.resizeto 300, 150
window.moveto 200, 200

for i = 0 to 32767
    show i
    ' your code here
next

window.close

function show(value)
    on error resume next
    window.output.innerhtml = value
    if err then wscript.quit
end function

function createwindow()
    ' source http://forum.script-coding.com/viewtopic.php?pid=75356#p75356
    dim signature, shellwnd, proc
    on error resume next
    set createwindow = nothing
    signature = left(createobject("Scriptlet.TypeLib").guid, 38)
    set proc = createobject("WScript.Shell").exec("mshta about:""<script>moveTo(-32000,-32000);</script><hta:application id=app border=dialog minimizebutton=no maximizebutton=no scroll=no showintaskbar=yes contextmenu=no selection=no innerborder=no /><object id='shellwindow' classid='clsid:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2'><param name=RegisterAsBrowser value=1></object><script>shellwindow.putproperty('" & signature & "',document.parentWindow);</script>""")
    do
        if proc.status > 0 then exit function
        for each shellwnd in createobject("Shell.Application").windows
            set createwindow = shellwnd.getproperty(signature)
            if err.number = 0 then exit function
            err.clear
        next
    loop
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will display how many loops it took and the value of a variable during the loop, and display the results in 1 message box after the loop is complete.

```
Dim RateOfChange, roc, watchvariable : roc = 1 : watchvariable = 1

for i=1 to 25
    watchvariable = (watchvariable * i) * 16
    RateOfChange = RateOfChange & "Iteration[" & roc & "]" & " - Value[" & watchvariable & "]" & vbcrlf
    roc = roc + 1
next

'NOTE uncomment this below to activate msgbox. 
'msgbox rateofchange
wscript.echo rateofchange
```