# need to create a loop macro IBM i (as400)

Tags: ibm-midrange

Could someone help me to write a macro for AS400 program that will refresh a specific page every 5 minutes. It should be an infinite loop that I can stop by clicking the stop button in the program. I tried to record the macro, but I can`t figure out how to make the loop.

Thank you!

This is what I got when tried to record the macro... (.mac file)

```
[PCOMM SCRIPT HEADER]
LANGUAGE=VBSCRIPT
DESCRIPTION=
[PCOMM SCRIPT SOURCE]
OPTION EXPLICIT
autECLSession.SetConnectionByName(ThisSessionName)

REM This line calls the macro subroutine
subSub1_

sub subSub1_()
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf5]"

   autECLSession.autECLPS.WaitForAttrib 10,1,"00","3c",3,10000

   autECLSession.autECLPS.Wait 781 

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf5]"

   autECLSession.autECLPS.WaitForAttrib 10,1,"00","3c",3,10000

   autECLSession.autECLPS.Wait 1125 

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable

   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
   autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[pf5]"
end sub
```

Comment: Is this for the Client Access terminal emulator?  For an RPG program?  For a web page served by IBM i?  Please edit your question and show us what you tried.

Comment: yes , its the i series 5.9 and goes thru the emulator. thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to loop is DO WHILE or DO UNTIL.  You'll probably want to display a message box to ask the user to exit.  Try:

```
Do While 1 = 1
   subSub1_
   result = MsgBox("Exit?", vbOK, "Exit?")
   If result = vbOK
     Exit Do
   End If
Loop
```

Not tested.  See the [VBScript Language Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d1wf56tt.aspx) on the Microsoft MSDN web site for more information.  For more information on modal vs non-modal, see Stack Overflow question [22513413](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513413/msgbox-in-vbs-that-updates-with-value-of-variable)

Answer (score 0):

Create your display with DFRWRT(*yes) RSTDSP(*yes) then in CLP OVRDSPF Display WAITRCD(&SECONDS)

Your program will wake up after the number of &SECONDS expire. Program will become active and code accordingly to refresh each time it wakes up.