# Time out on msgbox

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript, timeout, msgbox

Is there a way to add a timeout to the message box so if there no input it defaults to no?

I would like it to default to No after 1 hour

```
@echo off
Call :YesNoBox "Are you sure you want to do that?"
if "%YesNo%"=="7" (
Call :MessageBox "You answered NO" "Heading"
exit /b
)

exit /b
:YesNoBox
REM returns 6 = Yes, 7 = No. Type=4 = Yes/No
set YesNo=
set MsgType=4
set heading=%~2
set message=%~1
echo wscript.echo msgbox(WScript.Arguments(0),%MsgType%,WScript.Arguments(1)) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"') do set YesNo=%%a
exit /b

:MessageBox
set heading=%~2
set message=%~1
echo msgbox WScript.Arguments(0),0,WScript.Arguments(1) >"%temp%\input.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"
exit /b
```

Comment: Do you want to handle the message box output in batch or vbsript file? One way to handle in vbs is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22513413/msgbox-in-vbs-that-updates-with-value-of-variable/22514184#22514184)

Comment: Found the answer for myself just add //T:36 to "cscript //nologo //T:36 "%temp%\input.vbs" "%message%" "%heading%"" and it will time out after 36 secs

Comment: @user14875 - clever workaround.

Comment: `intButton = wshshell.Popup(strText,[nSecondsToWait],[strTitle],[nType])` from  http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [**jscript/bat hybrid**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/yesnopopup.bat) script with yes/no buttons pop-up.It uses [popup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f(v=vs.84).aspx) object which has a time-out option:

```
 @if (@x)==(@y) @end /***** jscript comment ******
     @echo off

     cscript //E:JScript //nologo "%~f0" "%~nx0" %*
     exit /b 0

 @if (@x)==(@y) @end ******  end comment *********/


var wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
var args=WScript.Arguments;
var title=args.Item(0);

var timeout=-1;
var message="";

function printHelp() {
    WScript.Echo(title + "[-title Title] [-timeout m] [-message \"pop-up message\"]");
    WScript.Echo(title + "if time out not defined will wait only for button pressing");
}

if (WScript.Arguments.Length==1){
    runPopup();
    WScript.Quit(0);
}

if (args.Item(1).toLowerCase() == "-help" ||  args.Item(1).toLowerCase() == "-h" ) {
    printHelp();
    WScript.Quit(0);
}

if (WScript.Arguments.Length % 2 == 0 ) {
    WScript.Echo("Illegal arguments ");
    printHelp();
    WScript.Quit(10);
}

for (var arg = 1 ; arg<args.Length;arg=arg+2) {

    if (args.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-title") {
        title = args.Item(arg+1);
    }

    if (args.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-timeout") {
        timeout = parseInt(args.Item(arg+1));
        if (isNaN(timeout)) {
            timeout=-1;
        }
    }


    if (args.Item(arg).toLowerCase() == "-message") {
        message = args.Item(arg+1);
    }
}

function runPopup(){
    var btn = wshShell.Popup(message, timeout, title, 0x4 + 0x20);
    //WScript.Echo(btn)
    switch(btn) {
        // yes pressed.
        case 6:
            WScript.Echo("yes");
            WScript.Quit(btn);
            break;
        // no  pressed.
        case 7:
            WScript.Echo("no");
            WScript.Quit(btn);
            break;

        // Timed out.
        case -1:
           WScript.Echo("timeout");
           WScript.Quit(btn);
           break;
    }
}

runPopup();
```

to use it try something like :

```
for /f %%a in ('yesnopopup.bat -title "T.I.T.L.E." -timeout 5 -tom "timeout"  -message "Hello"') do (
  if "%%~a" equ "yes" echo YES PRESSED
  if "%%~a" equ "no" echo NO PRESSED
  if "%%~a" equ "timeout" echo TIMED OUT
)
```

I prefer using jscript/bat hybrids as it makes the code easier to read , they use a single file which reduces the i/o operations and everything is faster.